# what formula does python statsmodels library uses to compute the bp_stat value (the Q value for the Box Pierce test)

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, python, chi-squared-test, statsmodels

As far as I know, the $Q$ statistics is computed with the formula

$Q = N \sum_{j=1}^K \rho_j^2 $
I created an example where I compute $Q$ by hand and by using:\

```
sm.stats.acorr_ljungbox(X, lags=[20], return_df=True, boxpierce=True)
```

From the formula above I get $Q=98.90109886278258$,
from **statsmodels** I get

```
lb_stat       lb_pvalue       bp_stat    bp_pvalue
102.988873  3.661944e-13     102.474971     4.530947e-13
```

I understand that bp_stat is the Box-pierce Q statistics, right?

In this case, I get 102.474971.

Does anyone know what formula is Python (statsmodels) using here?

Thanks.
PD. I checked the manual and could not find it.

Comment: This is a programming/implementation question that doesn't seem to be on topic for Cross Validated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
but would be on topic at Stack Overflow instead:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python
Also consider looking into these Python resources:
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1090/17414

Comment: @civilstat : Thanks